# calipress wordpress text overlapping sidebar

Tags: wordpress, overlapping

now i have a problem that my text is overlapping to the sidebar. 
where can i fix this problem ?

here is the problem

http://www.deal4real.nl/ads/test-advertentie/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css `word-wrap: break-word;` property.

Output -

[image: Wordwrap]